# How do you hide the row actions behind the 3 dots in laravel-admin package?

Tags: php, laravel-admin

How do you create the row actions to be like this (screen shot from documentation)

[image]

To see just 3 dots and click on them and then show the buttons?

This is the laravel package I'm talking about:
https://github.com/z-song/laravel-admin

Docs: https://laravel-admin.org/docs/en/

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: PHP, but the thing is, that this is inside some custom made package and it probably has it's own way of doing this by extending.... so I thought to throw a question before I write it on my own. And the funny thing in the docs... he already has it like that. So I guess this is already "solved" I just couldn't find the code.

Comment: You could wrap this inside a div and set the div's properties to postion:absolute or relative and use css to move it around

Comment: So what I figured out... if you don't have any custom actions and you do this before returning the $grid in controller `$grid->setActionClass(Grid\Displayers\DropdownActions::class);`
It will show you 3 dots for the default laravel-admin actions.
But I still didn't figure out how to make it for custom made actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this question would be to simply use the

```
$grid->setActionClass(Grid\Displayers\DropdownActions::class);
```

which is enabled by default for laravel-admin in config `config/admin.php`

```
/*
|------------------------------------------------------------------------ --
| The global Grid action display class.
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
'grid_action_class' => \Encore\Admin\Grid\Displayers\DropdownActions::class,
```

But it was commented out in our project meaning it was disabled.

There is a catch also. If you have custom made RowAction you should use it like this:

```
$grid->actions(function ($actions) {
    $actions->add(new CustomRowAction());
}
```

---

```
namespace App\Admin\Actions\Document;

use Encore\Admin\Actions\RowAction;

class CustomRowAction extends RowAction
{
    public $name = 'Button name';

    public function handle()
    {
        // do something here
    }

    public function dialog()
    {
        $this->confirm('Are you sure?');
    }
}
```